# grunt install error: unable to find local grunt

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, package.json

I'm trying to run grunt but receiving this error. I have grunt installed globally and can run 'grunt watch' from other locations and it works for other files. I have a new project given to me which has less files, and it contains a package.json file (this seems buried, where I'd assume it should be closer to the root but I'm new to this). I try to run grunt watch from the root and receive the error message above. The package.json does not list grunt files as dependencies. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that it's missing locally. `npm scripts` run things out of the node_modules directory, so install `grunt` locally to resolve it.

`npm install grunt --save-dev`

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense, however now it's installed a 'node_modules' folder at the root of my project. When I attempt to run grunt watch at the root, or in the path of the less file, I get the error 'fatal error: unable to find Gruntfile'. Sorry for the hand holding, any advice?

Comment: It sounds like your grunt is now installed locally. However you are not running 'grunt watch' in the directory where Gruntfile.js is located. Hope that helps.

Comment: It doesn't sound like your project is actually set up to use grunt yet.  I'd encourage you to review Grunt's getting started guide to understand what you need to add to the project to run tasks.